# Rails conditional validation not working correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to setup a conditional validation, and whether or not the method I pass to it returns `true` or `false` the object will save.

When `test` returns `false`, I don't want the object to save

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :order
  belongs_to :user

  validates :order, presence: true
  validates :user, presence: true, if: :test

  private

  def test
    false
  end
end
```

controller:

```
def create
  foo = Foo.new(foo_params)

  if foo.save
    render json: delivery, status: 201
  else
    render json: { errors: foo }, status: 422
  end
end
```

Comment: if test is false, the user validation just will be skipped

Comment: Oh, I see.  I'm using the validation incorrectly.  How could I make the object not save if `test` returns false?

Comment: you can use `unless: :test` instead of `if:`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your case, if `:test` returns `false`, the `user` validation just will be skipped. But if you wish to force validation always to fail, replace validator and pass a value to it:

**app/validators/custom_presence_validator.rb**:

```
class CustomPresenceValidator < AM::EachValidator
   def validate_each record, attribute, value
      if options[:with].try(:[], :fail)
         record.errors[ attribute ] << 'forced fail'
      elsif value.blank?
         record.errors[ attribute ] << 'can\'t be blank'
      end
   end
end
```

and use it:

```
validates :user, custom_presence: { fail: true }
```

or you just can you `:before_save` too by your wish.

Comment: Is this a better solution than using `before_save`?